# Tracing a specified distance along a network using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, network-analyst, hydrology, geometric-network

Using ArcGIS Pro 3.1.

I have some starting points snapped to a network of river lines (purple in image). I would like to trace exactly 500m away from these points in either direction as below (red), like the *Limit trace length* option in *Trace Options* of the Trace tool.
[image]

Manually tracing these lines isn't an option as there are too many to trace. I would like to find a tool that can be incorporated into a Modelbuilder model.

I have tried making a Trace Network and using the *Shortest path* option, but have found that this requires 2 starting points and it doesn't quite seem to fit my exact requirements, it's really important that the trace is exactly 500m or less if there is a 'dead end' less than 500m away.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Function Barrier. Using the Add function will total the Shape_Length attribute and when it reaches the set value (in your case 500m) the trace will stop.

See section on Function Barriers:
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/trace-network/barriers.htm